# Como exibir e esconder Toogle dentro de ngfor corretamente?

Tags: javascript, angular, for

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
listNotas() {
    
    this.service.getList(this.idAluno).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.error = data.error;
        this.list = data.message;        
        console.log(this.list);        
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

```js
status:Boolean=false;
  myToggle(i){
    this.status[i] = true;
    console.log(this.status[i]);    
  }
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of list; let i = index">
    <span>
      {{data.aula}}
      <ion-toggle (click)="myToggle(i)"></ion-toggle>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="status == true">
      {{data.nome}}
    </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: não esta faltando acessar a variável status[i]? no if

Comment: Qual é o layout do json retornado?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, editei a pergunta e incluí uma imagem com o json retornado

Comment: @HenriqueMendesSilveiraRodri tem o campo status é por esse campo???

Comment: sim, mas a função do toogle é booleano e não to conseguindo utilizar esse campo para executar individualmente, dentro do ngFor...

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma de fazer isso seria:

Primeiro mapear a listar para cada elemento ter um status como false

```
array = array.map(obj = > { obj.status=false; return obj; })
```

Depois sua funcao de toggle pode ser assim:

```
myToggle(element){
  element.active = !element.active;    
}
```

finalmente no html

```
<div *ngFor="let data of list">
    <span>
      {{data.aula}}
      <ion-toggle (click)="myToggle(data)"></ion-toggle>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="data.status == true">
      {{data.nome}}
    </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Eduardo, editei a pergunta e acrescentei a função que chamo a lista do back-end, o mapeamento eu faria nessa função?

Comment: isso dentro do subscribe

Comment: Como que ficaria na função esse mapeamento? não to conseguindo fazer, talvez por ser typescritp...

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver e vou deixar a solução postada aqui:

```js
status:Boolean=false;
  myToggle(data){
    if(data.status === 1){
      data.status = 0;
    }else{
      data.status = 1;
    }    
    console.log(data.status)    
  }
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of list">
    <span>
      {{data.aula}} - {{data.status}}
      <button ion-button (click)="myToggle(data)">mostrar</button>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="data.status == 0">
      {{data.aula}}
    </span>
  </div>
```

por algum motivo o botão `<ion-toggle>` não funcionou...